# Complex representation of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H\trianglelefteq G$ (finite groups) and let $V$ be a (complex) representation of $G$, and let $W$ be a $H$ subrepresentation of the restriction of $V$ to $H$.

Does exist an irreducible $G-$subrepresentation of $V$ such that contains $W$? (i know that exists an irreducible $G-$subrepresentation of $V$ such that contains a $H-$subrepresentation isomorphic to $W$ but I want it to contain $W$)

Comment: No, take $H$ to be the trivial group and let $W$ be the span of any vector in $V$.

Comment: One should always, *always*, **always** look at extreme cases when asking this sort of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take H to be the trivial group and let W be the span of any vector in V. – Jonathan 21 hours ago